# Android add a menu item at runtime

Tags: android, menu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.about:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, impresszum.class);
            startActivity(i);

                return true;
            case R.id.quit:
                AppUtils.ExitTheApplication();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I have this code. I want to add some menu at runtime, when i need it. And remove some menu when i need it. How can I do that?

Comment: See [Creating Menus on the Android developers website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#intents) and focus on the *Dynamically adding menu intents* part.

Answer (score 3):

Menu items are not necessarily related to an activity like in the section suggested by Shelly, in which case you can call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` to get a hold on the menu object in order to "refresh" the menu in the subsequent call to `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`.

From [the same Android Developers site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#ChangingTheMenu):

> On Android 2.3.x and lower, the system calls [onPrepareOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29)
>   each time the user opens the options menu (presses the Menu button).
>
> On Android 3.0 and higher, the options menu is considered to always be
>   open when menu items are presented in the action bar. When an event
>   occurs and you want to perform a menu update, you must call
>   [invalidateOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29) to request that the system call
>   [onPrepareOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29).